# difference between util.inherits and Object.create()

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

What does `util.inherits` do more than the following code:

```
constructor.prototype = Object.create(superconstructor.prototype);
```

Comment: Because if you only want one class to inherit the methods from another class, making them share the exact same methods is completely wrong.

Comment: what about this 
`constructor.prototype = Object.create(superconstructor.prototype);`
@Oriol

Comment: Yes, but then restoring the `constructor` property is a good idea: `constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor`. Or with `defineProperty` to make it non-enumerable.

Comment: and why should I to set the constructor property ? @Oriol
I guess to retrieve the constructor later from an instance so that I can create a new one, right ??